# Redirect for urls with filename and query string

Tags: magento-1.9, 301-redirect

I basically know how to import and redirect urls with the Magento URL Rewrite Tool.

Now I have the case that I need to redirect

`shop/shop.php?blbla=238746t2345` to the product.

I prepared and imported everything but as the string contains .php it seems to be ignored by the rewrite tool.

Is there any workaround for this?

Could I rewrite maybe `shop.php` to `shop-php` by htaccess before and the rewrite it again with the rewrite tool?

What would be the htaccess directive for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `RedirectMatch` in order to redirect URLs with parameters. For Example:

`RedirectMatch 301    /shop.php?id=17299    /target-url.html`

Put them after `RewriteEngine on`, but before the first `RewriteRule`.

Comment: Hi Andreas and thanks for the answer. This is how didi it finally. I first though I could use magentos rewrite management better for it, but doing it with a server rewrite was much easier.